# Not able to get cookie value on other page in magento

Tags: php, magento, cookies, setcookie

Hi I have set a cookie in Magento as:

```
$cookie_value = $_GET["utm_source"];
$cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
$name   = "Pixel_Track";
$url    = "stage.test.com";
$expiry = time() + 86400 * 365 * 1;
$cookie->set($name, $cookie_value ,$url,$expiry);
```

Now I want to get on another page and I am using:

```
$cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->get($name);
```

Where I am doing wrong? Because `print_r` is not giving the cookie name.

Answer (score 1):

`Mage_Core_Model_Cookie` class contains functions to set, get and delete cookie. so try:

```
$cookie_value = $_GET["utm_source"];
$cookie = Mage::getModel('core/cookie');
...
$cookie->set($name, $cookie_value, $period ,$url,$expiry);
```

and

```
$cookie = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the solution by defining the `path` attribute of cookie.

`$cookie->set($name, $cookie_value ,time()+86400,'/');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $cookie = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get("Pixel_Track");
```

//your can't get your variables in another page, so please type cookie name.